# `std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource`: why the `dynamic_cast`?

Tags: c++, c++17, dynamic-cast, allocator

The draft standard N4618 says this about `std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource`:

> ```
> bool do_is_equal(const memory_resource& other) const noexcept override;
> ```
>
> Returns: `this == dynamic_cast<const monotonic_buffer_resource*>(&other)`

In other words, rather than just comparing the pointers for equality with `this == &rhs`, the Standard wants the vendor to go out of their way to `dynamic_cast` the right-hand pointer.

I can't think of any *sane* situation in which the `dynamic_cast` would change the outcome of the comparison. I can think of some *insane* cases, though:

```
class new_delete_memory_resource : public memory_resource {
    void *do_allocate(size_t bytes, size_t align) override {
        return ::operator new(bytes, align);
    }
    void *do_deallocate(void *p, size_t bytes, size_t align) override {
        ::operator delete(p, bytes, align);
    }
    bool do_is_equal(const memory_resource& rhs) const noexcept override {
        return (this == &rhs);
    }
};
class TwoHeadedResource :
    public new_delete_memory_resource,
    public monotonic_buffer_resource
{
};

TwoHeadedResource thr;
memory_resource *a = static_cast<new_delete_memory_resource *>(thr);
memory_resource *b = static_cast<monotonic_buffer_resource *>(thr);

assert(*a != *b);
assert(*b == *a);
```

Is there a subtle reason for this discrepancy? What would have gone wrong if the Standard had made `operator==` reflexive/symmetric/transitive by removing the `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: `this == &other` doesn't make sense, since the two operands have different types?!

Comment: @kerreksb Eh? `&other` is of static type `memory_resource*` and `this` is of static type `monotonic_buffer_resource*`, which is implicitly convertible to `memory_resource*`. This is classical OO inheritance, isn't it?

Comment: What is the whole point of that do_is_equal virtual if it has to compare memory_resource object addresses?

Comment: @ÖöTiib: `do_is_equal` is a private virtual method provided by the base class `std::pmr::memory_resource`. See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/memory_resource) for the details, which I think are out of scope for this particular question.

Comment: The number of people who is familiar enough with `pmr`'s design to answer those questions can be counted on one hand or two. The number of such people who also frequent SO is approximately zero.

Comment: IOW, go email Pablo Halpern.

Comment: @T.C.: Okay, I've done that. Turns out he's OOO until September, though, so I don't expect an authoritative response anytime soon. Surely, though, there's at least one other person in the world who understands this part of the draft standard? I mean a bunch of people voted it in; surely at least a few of them read it first. :P

Comment: Ok, read it, can't find new_delete_memory_resource there that you post, new_delete_resource is there but is a function so can't be base class. However it indeed looks that dynamic_cast is not needed when equal can be only same object with itself.

Comment: @Öö Tiib: The reason that `do_is_equal` is virtual is that not all memory resource types must be identity equal in order to compare equal. It just so happens that `monotonic_buffer_resource` compares addresses, but other resources do not -- most notably `resource_adaptor<A>`, which is not yet in the standard but can be found on page 90 of http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4617.pdf. (The `do_is_equal` function using `dynamic_cast` is at the top of page 91.)

Comment: @ÖöTiib: Just for the record: yeah, I had to implement `new_delete_memory_resource` myself because it's not standardized. If it were standard, I wouldn't have had to implement it! :) (I required a definition of the actual type `new_delete_memory_resource` only because I wanted to inherit from it for this example, which is pretty contrived.)

Comment: @Quuxplusone: Ah indeed, I thought we were doing a downcast from a virtual base. The upcast should indeed work without a dynamic cast!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known defect, though your question does remind me that I need to file a formal issue report.

The simple formulation of `this == &other` is what it should be. The `dynamic_cast` is a hold-over from some boilerplate code whereby the rhs of the equality does not have to be the same object as the lhs in order to be considered equal.  In the most general case, if two `pmr::memory_resource` objects are interchangeable but don't have the same address, you'll have to dynamically cast the rhs to the type of the lhs in order to determine equality.  However, in the case of `pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource`, address equality is required, so the `dynamic_cast` is superfluous.

Your `TwoHeadedResource` is clever, though. Hats off to you for figuring out a situation where it would make a difference, even though that is not the type of code we aim to support. :-)

EDIT: There is now an official issue report for this defect at http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#3000.

Comment: Thanks Pablo! Over the past few months I've decided that `dynamic_cast` is a code smell, because code that requires it is ultra-rare and code that uses it has an ultra-low chance of using it correctly. Come to my CppCon 2017 talk "`dynamic_cast` from scratch" to hear me vent about that (but mostly about how [no vendor *implements* it correctly](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/from-scratch/tree/master/dynamic-cast), not that that matters, since code that requires it is ultra-rare).

Comment: Thanks, @Quuxplusone. I'll look for that talk. You can also look for my talk: Allocators - the good parts, at this CppCon.  With luck, they won't be in the same time slot.